# Can I use "not equal" in MS Access Find Function

Tags: ms-access

Can i use the qualifier "not equal" in the ms access find function? I have a column of numbers that are the same for most records but an occasional different number gets in the list and i want to find these different number every time they occur.

Answer (score 3):

Qualifier "not equal" is <>

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to the Find / Replace option in the datasheet view of a table, then no - you cannot use a "not equal" option.

You can, however, filter the data or use a query in order to find the appropriate records.

To use a filter, right-click on the column in the datasheet to access the filter options.   Versions of Access prior to 2007 will require you to type ***<> "Value"*** in the filter textbox.

To use a query, create a new query and add the fields from your table that you need to work with.  Add the column you wish to filter on, and in the criteria box enter ***<> "Value"***