# Microsoft Access SQL Query - get rid of certain results

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want to find lecture rooms (their room code) which are of capacity 100 or more and are free (i.e. not booked) on Tuesday at 12pm.

In the room table, there are rCode & capacity.
In the roomBooking table, there are dayReq, timeReq & roomCode.

The SQL Query I have so far is

```
SELECT rCode, capacity 
FROM room
INNER JOIN roomBooking
ON room.rCode = roomBooking.roomCode
WHERE capacity >= 100;
```

I want to get rid of the results that involve
dayReq = "Tuesday" AND timeReq = "12:00:00" but I don't know the correct operator to do so.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18886128/can-i-use-not-equal-in-ms-access-find-function

You can use not equal operator. Have you Googled this?

Comment: @SurgeonofDeath . . . The not-equal operator has nothing to do with the answer to this question.

Comment: She does not want the results that has the Tuesday for dayReq and timeReq. I thought thats what the question has indicated.

"I want to get rid of the results that involve dayReq = "Tuesday" AND timeReq = "12:00:00" but I don't know the correct operator to do so."?

Comment: @SurgeonofDeath . . . Read the first sentence.  The OP is looking for non-matches in the two tables, according to the timing conditions.

Comment: @GordonLinoff How does your query gets rid of results that involves dayReq="Tuesday" and rimeReq = "12:00:00"?

Answer (score 1):

To get what you want, you are going to need a `left join` (or a subquery in the `where` clause).  The idea is to find get all rooms along with any possible matches the room has to the booking criteria.  You then want the rooms where there is no match:

```
SELECT room.rCode, room.capacity 
FROM room LEFT JOIN
     roomBooking
     ON room.rCode = roomBooking.roomCode AND
        dayReq = 'Tuesday' AND timeReq = '12:00:00'
WHERE room.capacity >= 100 AND
      roomBooking.roomCode IS NULL;
```

MS Access is really weird about many things, including joins with multiple keys.  Just do this with a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT room.rCode, room.capacity 
FROM room
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM roomBooking
                  WHERE room.rCode = roomBooking.roomCode AND
                        dayReq = "Tuesday" AND timeReq = "12:00:00"
                 ) AND
      room.capacity >= 100;
```

Comment: Does not she want to get rid of results that involve these values? Won't this query give her the results that includes those variables?

Comment: @SurgeonofDeath . . . This will return the rooms that have no booking at that particular time.

Comment: @GordonLinoff when I try this, I get "JOIN expression not supported."

Comment: @ChloeConlon . . . What database are you using? Both SQL Server and Access support `LEFT JOIN`.  You might try `left outer join` to see if that works.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm using Access. Tried the left outer join and still getting the same outcome.

Comment: @GordonLinoff and when this error comes up, dayReq = "Tuesday" is highlighted.